# Struct/Malloc or Other? SIGSEGV Error

Tags: c

I have debugged and watched my "watch window" to get an idea where the problem was. It does not even finish the code though. During the test sequence to find the user inputted word, it fails. It has a SIGSEGV fault at the found function.

The code is meant to take in a word puzzle and then allow the user to find the words.

puzzleInput.txt:

```
M,N,O,S,L,I,W,E,R,E,L,Y,T,L,E,A,G,N
A,H,O,O,V,E,R,T,A,Y,L,O,R,V,E,N,N,A
D,F,D,R,O,O,S,E,V,E,L,T,O,N,O,M,I,M
I,N,T,P,M,H,I,E,G,D,I,L,O,O,C,O,D,U
S,O,N,L,I,J,Q,A,D,A,M,S,S,R,N,N,R,R
O,X,L,O,G,E,F,F,M,O,I,R,E,E,G,R,A,T
N,I,B,T,S,O,R,A,O,R,M,O,V,A,W,O,H,N
F,N,H,U,R,R,B,C,R,N,L,R,E,G,B,E,W,E
R,O,S,D,C,O,E,A,E,I,O,N,L,A,U,A,J,R
K,W,U,N,L,H,H,F,N,I,O,S,T,N,S,W,A,U
E,R,B,A,J,B,A,C,F,S,S,M,N,H,H,R,D,B
N,E,W,L,O,T,O,N,K,E,C,E,I,H,T,H,A,N
N,T,H,E,H,L,A,C,A,K,J,N,N,H,O,I,M,A
E,R,G,V,N,C,A,F,I,N,G,H,U,H,A,J,S,V
D,A,R,E,S,J,C,N,T,T,A,R,N,B,O,Y,A,E
Y,C,A,L,O,D,L,N,O,S,I,R,R,A,H,W,E,O
N,E,N,C,N,E,T,N,N,O,T,N,I,L,C,O,E,S
D,A,T,Y,Y,P,O,L,K,G,A,R,F,I,E,L,D,R

enter code here
```

code:

```
/*  This program reads a puzzle from a file
    and allows the user to define a word which
    they want to find in the word puzzle.*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void fileNam(char[]);
char showMenu();
int fileData(char*);
void alphaArray();
void getUser();
void fileError(char*);
void findUserFirst();
int createString();
void found(int);
void notFound(char*);
void goToExit();
void display();

struct alphabet
{
      int *A;int *B; int *C; int *D; int *E; int *F;
      int *G; int *H; int *I; int *J; int *K; int *L; int *M;
      int *N; int *O; int *P; int *Q; int *R; int *S;
      int *T; int *U; int *V; int *W; int *X; int *Y; int *Z;
      int a; int b; int c; int d; int e; int f; int g; int h; int i; int j; int k; int l; int m;
      int n; int o; int p; int q; int r; int s; int t; int u; int v; int w; int x; int y; int z;
}fill;

struct user
{
    struct alphabet* ptr;
    int *attempt;
    int testNum;
    int columns;
    int rows;
    int userSize;
    int puzzleSize;
    char *puzzleArray;
    char userWord[45];
}test;


int main()
{
    int wordsFound = 0;
    int fileErr = 0;
    int wordF = 0;
    char option;
    char fileLoc[100] = {0};

    do
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        option = showMenu();
        fflush(stdin);

        if(fileErr == -1)
        {
            fileError(fileLoc);
        }

        switch(option)
        {
            case 'a':;
                fileNam(fileLoc);
                strcat(fileLoc,"\\puzzleInput.txt");
                fileErr = fileData(fileLoc);
                break;
            case 'b':
                display();
                break;
            case 'c':
                getUser();
                findUserFirst();
                wordF = 0;
                do{
                    wordF = createString();
                    if(wordF > 0)
                    {
                        found(wordF);
                        wordsFound++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        test.ptr;
                    }
                    }while(*test.attempt <= test.testNum);
                    if(wordF < -1)
                        notFound(fileLoc);
                break;
            case 'd':
                goToExit(wordsFound);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid selection.\nPlease choose again.\n");
                break;
        }
    }while(option != 'd');


    return 0;
}

char showMenu()
{
    char option;
    printf("Choose one of the following:\n");
    printf("\ta. Enter file location(full path)\n");
    printf("\tb. Display the puzzle\n");
    printf("\tc. Find a word\n");
    printf("\td. Exit\n");
    option = getchar();
    return option;
}

void goToExit(int found)
{
    printf("\nYou found %d words!\n", found);
    if(found > 5)
    {
        printf("Awesome job! Come back to play again!");
    }
    else{
        printf("Better luck next time!");
    }
    printf("Press any key to close window.");
    getchar();
    free(fill.A);free(fill.B); free(fill.C); free(fill.D); free(fill.E); free(fill.F);
    free(fill.G); free(fill.H); free(fill.I); free(fill.J); free(fill.K); free(fill.L); free(fill.M);
    free(fill.N); free(fill.O); free(fill.P); free(fill.Q); free(fill.R); free(fill.S);
    free(fill.T); free(fill.U); free(fill.V); free(fill.W); free(fill.X); free(fill.Y); free(fill.Z);
    free(test.puzzleArray);
}

void display()
{
    int i, j, k = 0;
    for(i=0; i <= test.columns; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j <= test.rows; j++)
        {
            printf("%c, ", test.puzzleArray[k]);
            k++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}


void fileNam(char fileLoc[])
{
    printf("When entering file location, do not \n");
    printf("include the file name.\nLOCATION:\n");
    gets(fileLoc);
}

void fileError(char* fileName)
{
    printf("There was an error with the file location");
    printf(" that you typed in.\nPlease make sure file ");
    printf("location and name are correct.\nIf name is wrong, ");
    printf("please change the name of your file to match.\n");
    printf("FILE LOCATION AND NAME: \"%s\"\n\n", fileName);
}

int fileData(char* fname)
{
    int i = 0;
    char curr;
    FILE * fPtr;
    fPtr = fopen(fname, "r");

    char buffer[1000] = {0};

    if(fPtr == NULL)//test if file opened
    {
        printf("There has been an error in opening %s!\n", fname);
        return -1;
    }

    while (!feof(fPtr))
    {
        fgets(buffer, 1000, fPtr);
        test.rows++;
    }

    rewind(fPtr);

    while(fgetc(fPtr) >= 65 && fgetc(fPtr) <= 90)
    {
        test.puzzleSize++;
    }

    test.puzzleArray = (char*) malloc((test.puzzleSize) * sizeof(char));
    printf("%d", test.puzzleSize);
    rewind(fPtr);
    i = 0;
    while ((curr = fgetc(fPtr)) != EOF)
    {
        if(curr == ',' || curr == '\n')
        {
            if(curr == '\n')
                test.columns++;
        }
        if(curr >= 65 && curr <= 90)
        {
            test.puzzleArray[i] = curr;
            i++;
        }

    }

    fclose(fPtr);
    alphaArray();
    return 0;
}

void alphaArray()
{
    int i = 0;
    char current = 0;


    while(test.puzzleArray[i] != '\0')
    {
        current = test.puzzleArray[i];
        switch(tolower(current))//accidentally coded lowercase, quick fix
        {
        case 'a':
            fill.a++;
            break;
        case 'b':
            fill.b++;
            break;
        case 'c':
            fill.c++;
            break;
        case 'd':
            fill.d++;
            break;
        case 'e':
            fill.e++;
            break;
        case 'f':
            fill.f++;
            break;
        case 'g':
            fill.g++;
            break;
        case 'h':
            fill.h++;
            break;
        case 'i':
            fill.i++;
            break;
        case 'j':
            fill.j++;
            break;
        case 'k':
            fill.k++;
            break;
        case 'l':
            fill.l++;
            break;
        case 'm':
            fill.m++;
            break;
        case 'n':
            fill.n++;
            break;
        case 'o':
            fill.o++;
            break;
        case 'p':
            fill.p++;
            break;
        case 'q':
            fill.q++;
            break;
        case 'r':
            fill.r++;
            break;
        case 's':
            fill.s++;
            break;
        case 't':
            fill.t++;
            break;
        case 'u':
            fill.u++;
            break;
        case 'v':
            fill.v++;
            break;
        case 'w':
            fill.w++;
            break;
        case 'x':
            fill.x++;
            break;
        case 'y':
            fill.y++;
            break;
        case 'z':
            fill.z++;
            break;
        default: printf("\n");
        break;
        }
    i++;
    }

    fill.A = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.a); fill.B = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.b);
    fill.C = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.c); fill.D = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.d);
    fill.E = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.e); fill.F = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.f);
    fill.G = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.g); fill.H = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.h);
    fill.I = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.i); fill.J = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.j);
    fill.K = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.k); fill.L = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.l);
    fill.M = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.m); fill.N = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.n);
    fill.O = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.o); fill.P = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.p);
    fill.Q = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.q); fill.R = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.r);
    fill.S = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.s); fill.T = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.t);
    fill.U = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.u); fill.V = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.v);
    fill.W = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.w); fill.X = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.x);
    fill.Y = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.y); fill.Z = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*fill.z);

    fill.a = 0;fill.b =0; fill.c =0; fill.d =0; fill.e =0; fill.f =0;
    fill.g =0; fill.k =0; fill.o =0; fill.s =0; fill.w =0;
    fill.h =0; fill.l =0; fill.p =0; fill.t =0; fill.x =0;
    fill.i =0; fill.m =0; fill.q =0; fill.u =0; fill.y =0;
    fill.j =0; fill.n =0; fill.r =0; fill.v =0; fill.z =0;
    i = 0;

    while(test.puzzleArray[i] != '\0')
    {
        current = test.puzzleArray[i];
        switch(tolower(current))//accidentally coded lowercase, quick fix
        {
        case 'a':
            fill.A[fill.a] = i;
            fill.a++;
            break;
        case 'b':
            fill.B[fill.b] = i;
            fill.b++;
            break;
        case 'c':
            fill.C[fill.c] = i;
            fill.c++;
            break;
        case 'd':
            fill.D[fill.d] = i;
            fill.d++;
            break;
        case 'e':
            fill.E[fill.e] = i;
            fill.e++;
            break;
        case 'f':
            fill.F[fill.f] = i;
            fill.f++;
            break;
        case 'g':
            fill.G[fill.g] = i;
            fill.g++;
            break;
        case 'h':
            fill.H[fill.h] = i;
            fill.h++;
            break;
        case 'i':
            fill.I[fill.i] = i;
            fill.i++;
            break;
        case 'j':
            fill.J[fill.j] = i;
            fill.j++;
            break;
        case 'k':
            fill.K[fill.k] = i;
            fill.k++;
            break;
        case 'l':
            fill.L[fill.l] = i;
            fill.l++;
            break;
        case 'm':
            fill.M[fill.m] = i;
            fill.m++;
            break;
        case 'n':
            fill.N[fill.n] = i;
            fill.n++;
            break;
        case 'o':
            fill.O[fill.o] = i;
            fill.o++;
            break;
        case 'p':
            fill.P[fill.p] = i;
            fill.p++;
            break;
        case 'q':
            fill.Q[fill.q] = i;
            fill.q++;
            break;
        case 'r':
            fill.R[fill.r] = i;
            fill.r++;
            break;
        case 's':
            fill.S[fill.s] = i;
            fill.s++;
            break;
        case 't':
            fill.T[fill.t] = i;
            fill.t++;
            break;
        case 'u':
            fill.U[fill.u] = i;
            fill.u++;
            break;
        case 'v':
            fill.V[fill.v] = i;
            fill.v++;
            break;
        case 'w':
            fill.W[fill.w] = i;
            fill.w++;
            break;
        case 'x':
            fill.X[fill.x] = i;
            fill.x++;
            break;
        case 'y':
            fill.Y[fill.y] = i;
            fill.y++;
            break;
        case 'z':
            fill.Z[fill.z] = i;
            fill.z++;
            break;
        default: printf("\n");
        break;
        }
    i++;
    }
}

void getUser()
{
    test.testNum = 0;
    test.userWord[45] = '\0';
    test.ptr = 0;
    printf("\nWhat word would you like to search for?\n");
    scanf("%s", test.userWord);
    test.userSize = strlen(test.userWord);
}

void findUserFirst()
{
    switch(tolower(test.userWord[0]))
    {
    case 'a':
        test.attempt = &fill.A[0];
        test.testNum = fill.a;
        break;
    case 'b':
        test.attempt = &fill.B[0];
        test.testNum =  fill.b;
        break;
    case 'c':
        test.attempt = &fill.C[0];
        test.testNum =  fill.c;
        break;
    case 'd':
        test.attempt = &fill.D[0];
        test.testNum =  fill.d;
        break;
    case 'e':
        test.attempt = &fill.E[0];
        test.testNum =  fill.e;
        break;
    case 'f':
        test.attempt = &fill.F[0];
        test.testNum =  fill.f;
        break;
    case 'g':
        test.attempt = &fill.G[0];
        test.testNum =  fill.g;
        break;
    case 'h':
        test.attempt = &fill.H[0];
        test.testNum =  fill.h;
        break;
    case 'i':
        test.attempt = &fill.I[0];
        test.testNum =  fill.i;
        break;
    case 'j':
        test.attempt = &fill.J[0];
        test.testNum =  fill.j;
        break;
    case 'k':
        test.attempt = &fill.K[0];
        test.testNum =  fill.k;
        break;
    case 'l':
        test.attempt = &fill.L[0];
        test.testNum =  fill.l;
        break;
    case 'm':
        test.attempt = &fill.M[0];
        test.testNum =  fill.m;
        break;
    case 'n':
        test.attempt = &fill.N[0];
        test.testNum =  fill.n;
        break;
    case 'o':
        test.attempt = &fill.O[0];
        test.testNum =  fill.o;
        break;
    case 'p':
        test.attempt = &fill.P[0];
        test.testNum =  fill.p;
        break;
    case 'q':
        test.attempt = &fill.Q[0];
        test.testNum =  fill.q;
        break;
    case 'r':
        test.attempt = &fill.R[0];
        test.testNum =  fill.r;
        break;
    case 's':
        test.attempt = &fill.S[0];
        test.testNum =  fill.s;
        break;
    case 't':
        test.attempt = &fill.T[0];
        test.testNum =  fill.t;
        break;
    case 'u':
        test.attempt = &fill.U[0];
        test.testNum =  fill.u;
        break;
    case 'v':
        test.attempt = &fill.V[0];
        test.testNum =  fill.v;
        break;
    case 'w':
        test.attempt = &fill.W[0];
        test.testNum =  fill.w;
        break;
    case 'x':
        test.attempt = &fill.X[0];
        test.testNum =  fill.x;
        break;
    case 'y':
        test.attempt = &fill.Y[0];
        test.testNum =  fill.y;
        break;
    case 'z':
        test.attempt = &fill.Z[0];
        test.testNum = fill.z;
        break;
    default: printf("\n");
    }
}

int createString()
{

    int i = 0, upRoom = 0, rightRoom = 0;
    int leftRoom = 0, downRoom = 0;
    int columnPos = 0, rowPos = 0;
    int arPos = 0;
    int moveup = 0, moveupr = 0;
    int moveupl = 0, mover = 0;
    int movel = 0, moved = 0;
    int movedr = 0, movedl = 0;
    char up[45];
    char upRight[45];
    char right[45];
    char downRight[45];
    char down[45];
    char downLeft[45];
    char left[45];
    char upLeft[45];


    arPos = *test.attempt;

    columnPos = arPos / test.columns;
    rowPos = arPos % test.rows;

    upRoom = test.columns/2 - columnPos;
    downRoom = test.columns/2 - columnPos;
    rightRoom = test.rows/2 - rowPos;
    leftRoom =  test.rows/2 - rowPos;

    moveup = -(test.rows);
    moveupr = (test.rows - 1) * (-1),
    moveupl = -(test.rows + 1);
    mover = 1;
    movel = 1;
    moved = test.rows,
    movedr = 1 * (test.rows + 1);
    movedl = 1 * (test.rows - 1);

    for(i=0; i < test.userSize; i++)
    {
        if(rightRoom >= 0)
        {
            right[i] = test.puzzleArray[arPos + i*mover];
            if(upRoom >= 0)
                upRight[i] = test.puzzleArray[arPos + i*moveupr];
            if(downRoom >= 0)
                downRight[i] = test.puzzleArray[arPos + i*movedr];
        }
        if(leftRoom >= 0)
        {
            left[i] = test.puzzleArray[arPos - movel];
            if(upRoom >= 0)
                upLeft[i] = test.puzzleArray[arPos + i*moveupl];
            if(downRoom >= 0)
                downLeft[i] = test.puzzleArray[arPos + i*movedl];
        }
        if(upRoom >= 0)
            up[i] = test.puzzleArray[arPos + i*moveup];
        if(downRoom >= 0)
            down[i] = test.puzzleArray[arPos + i*moved];
    }

    for(i = 0; i < test.userSize; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(up, test.userWord) == 0)
            return 1;
        if(strcmp(upRight, test.userWord) == 0)
            return 2;
        if(strcmp(right, test.userWord) == 0)
            return 3;
        if(strcmp(downRight, test.userWord) == 0)
            return 4;
        if(strcmp(down, test.userWord) == 0)
            return 5;
        if(strcmp(downLeft, test.userWord) == 0)
            return 6;
        if(strcmp(left, test.userWord) == 0)
            return 7;
        if(strcmp(upLeft, test.userWord) == 0)
            return 8;
        else
            return -1;
    }
    return -1;
}

void found(int style)
{
    int pos = 0, movement = 0;
    int i, j, k = 0;
    char *cpyPuzzle;

    cpyPuzzle = (char*) malloc((test.puzzleSize) * sizeof(char));

    strcpy(cpyPuzzle, test.puzzleArray);


    switch(style){
        case 1:
            movement = test.rows;
            break;
        case 2:
            movement = test.rows - 1;
            break;
        case 3:
            movement = 1;
            break;
        case 4:
            movement = test.rows + 1;
            break;
        case 5:
            movement = test.rows;
            break;
        case 6:
            movement = test.rows - 1;
            break;
        case 7:
            movement = 1;
            break;
        case 8:
            movement = test.rows + 1;
            break;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < test.puzzleSize; i++)
    {
        cpyPuzzle[i] = '~';
    }

    for(i=0; i < test.userSize; i++)
    {
        pos = test.attempt + (i*movement);
        cpyPuzzle[pos] = test.userWord[i];
    }

    for(i=0; i < test.columns; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j < test.rows; j++)
        {
            printf("%c, ", cpyPuzzle[k]);
            k++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(cpyPuzzle);
}
void notFound(char *fileN)
{
    printf("In file %s %c was not found.\n", test.userWord, fileN);
    printf("You can try finding another word");
    printf(" by pressing the option to show puzzle and\n");
    printf("then the option to find a word, once you've found one.\n");
}
```

Comment: What line does the debugger say the seg-fault occurred on?

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is bad - `fflush` is only valid for output streams.

Comment: In your `switch` ==>> `case 'c':` in the `else` part you have a statement with no efect, which is `test.ptr;` Check on that. What should `test.ptr` should do here?

Comment: `test.userWord[45] = '\0';` write to out of bounds.

Comment: `void goToExit();` ==>> `void goToExit(int);` Don't use `gets`, is deprecated.

Comment: A compilation gave 2 warnings. In `pos = test.attempt + (i*movement);` the warning " '=': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'int *' ". And in `printf("In file %s %c was not found.\n", test.userWord, fileN);` the warning " 'printf' : format string '%c' requires an argument of type 'int', but variadic argument 2 has type 'char *' ". Better fix all warnings.

Comment: Line 598 is causing the problem. arPos= *test.attempt. attempt is pointing to NULL. Perhaps you need to provide an input file so we can run the code...

Comment: Here => `printf("In file %s %c was not found.\n", test.userWord, fileN);` also ==>> `error: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘char *’` You have a lot of errors and conversion problems.

Comment: Please provide an input file.....

Comment: Where was the error?

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

SOLVED! - the error was I was not dereferencing and then referencing a pointer.